# Add 3 rows per page to IText Document

Tags: c#, itext

I am looking to output 3 rows per page from a datatable into an itextsharp document, but it just lumps all the rows into one table, could someone show me the error of my ways?

```
                    //Create new table and set columns and widths for Report Items
                    PdfPTable itemTable = new PdfPTable(4);

                    //Loop each row in the dataset and output
                    for (int i = 0; i < repDT.Rows.Count; i += 3)
                    {
                        float[] ITWidths = new float[] { 10f, 20f, 10f, 60f };  //4 columns by size (f) for list of multi-items on report
                        itemTable.SetWidths(ITWidths);

                        PdfPCell datesvalues = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("" + repDT.Rows[i]["OLDDATE"] + "\n" + Convert.ToDateTime(repDT.Rows[i]["INSDATE"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "\n" + Convert.ToDateTime(repDT.Rows[i]["NEXT DATE"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyy") + "\n" + repDT.Rows[i]["CONT FREQ"].ToString() + " months", smalltext));
                        itemTable.AddCell(datesvalues);
                        PdfPCell itemdetails = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("1. " + repDT.Rows[i]["DESC"] + "\n" + "2. " + repDT.Rows[i]["PLANTNUMBER"] + "\n" + "3. " + repDT.Rows[i]["SERIALNUMBER"] + "\n" + "4. " + repDT.Rows[i]["SUBLOC"].ToString(), smalltext));
                        itemTable.AddCell(itemdetails);
                        PdfPCell swl = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("" + repDT.Rows[i]["SWL"], smalltext));
                        itemTable.AddCell(swl);
                        PdfPCell defects = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("A. " + repDT.Rows[i]["ADEFECT"] + "\n" + "B. " + repDT.Rows[i]["BDEFECT"] + "\n" + "C. " + repDT.Rows[i]["OBS"] + "\n" + "" + repDT.Rows[i]["SPARE1"].ToString(), smalltext));
                        itemTable.AddCell(defects);

                        document.NewPage();
                    }

                    document.Add(itemTable);
```

Comment: why do you add `itemTable` to an unknown `mTable` instead of to the `document`?

Comment: mkl, I have a main table that I use to add other items on the document.  Is this where I am going wrong?

Comment: well, if you use that main table, those `document.NewPage()` have no effect because they all occur before your main table is added and iText does not add unnecessary empty pages.

Comment: Thanks for your help mkl, I will give that a shot.

Comment: mkl, I have modified the code above and taken out the redundant main table, moved the new table (itemtable) out of the loop but it still shows itemtable as one table without the new pages between every 3 rows?  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't add any content to the document inside the loop, so the `document.NewPage()` calls therein are ignored.

Simply pull in the instantiation and to-document-adding of the table into the loop:

```
//Loop each row in the dataset and output
for (int i = 0; i < repDT.Rows.Count; i += 3)
{
    //Create new table and set columns and widths for Report Items
    PdfPTable itemTable = new PdfPTable(4);
    float[] ITWidths = new float[] { 10f, 20f, 10f, 60f };  //4 columns by size (f) for list of multi-items on report
    itemTable.SetWidths(ITWidths);

    PdfPCell datesvalues = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("" + repDT.Rows[i]["OLDDATE"] + "\n" + Convert.ToDateTime(repDT.Rows[i]["INSDATE"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "\n" + Convert.ToDateTime(repDT.Rows[i]["NEXT DATE"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyy") + "\n" + repDT.Rows[i]["CONT FREQ"].ToString() + " months", smalltext));
    itemTable.AddCell(datesvalues);
    PdfPCell itemdetails = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("1. " + repDT.Rows[i]["DESC"] + "\n" + "2. " + repDT.Rows[i]["PLANTNUMBER"] + "\n" + "3. " + repDT.Rows[i]["SERIALNUMBER"] + "\n" + "4. " + repDT.Rows[i]["SUBLOC"].ToString(), smalltext));
    itemTable.AddCell(itemdetails);
    PdfPCell swl = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("" + repDT.Rows[i]["SWL"], smalltext));
    itemTable.AddCell(swl);
    PdfPCell defects = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("A. " + repDT.Rows[i]["ADEFECT"] + "\n" + "B. " + repDT.Rows[i]["BDEFECT"] + "\n" + "C. " + repDT.Rows[i]["OBS"] + "\n" + "" + repDT.Rows[i]["SPARE1"].ToString(), smalltext));
    itemTable.AddCell(defects);

    document.Add(itemTable);

    document.NewPage();
}
```

Comment: Excellent mkl, Thank you for all your help.